# Hands of Straights (LeetCode) Arrange the card

Tags: haskell

Tried this leetcode question Hands of Straights. https://leetcode.com/problems/hand-of-straights/
Description is 
Alice has a hand of cards, given as an array of integers.

Now she wants to rearrange the cards into groups so that each group is size W, and consists of W consecutive cards.

Return true if and only if she can.

```
Example 1.
Input: hand = [1,2,3,6,2,3,4,7,8], W = 3
Output: true
Explanation: Alice's hand can be rearranged as [1,2,3],[2,3,4],[6,7,8].

Example 2
Input: hand = [1,2,3,4,5], W = 4
Output: false
Explanation: Alice's hand can't be rearranged into groups of 4.
```

My attempt to solve it using Haskell is here. Can someone review it. The code returns the correct values for most of the test cases that I have tried.

```
import Data.List

{-
solve 3 [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4]
True

solve 3 [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
False

solve 4 [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
True
-}

solve::Int -> [Int] -> Bool
solve v xss = helper v $ group $ sort xss

helper::Int ->[[Int]] -> Bool
helper v [] = True
helper v xss = let (a, b) = splitAt v xss 
    in case verify a  && ((length a) `mod` v == 0)  of
        True -> helper v $ (removeHead a []) ++ b
        False -> False

verify::[[Int]] -> Bool
verify [] = True
verify (x:[]) = True
verify (x:y:zx) 
    | head y == succ (head x) = verify $ y:zx
    | otherwise = False

removeHead::[[Int]] -> [[Int]]-> [[Int]]
removeHead [] acc = acc
removeHead (x:xss) acc = case null (tail x) of
    True -> removeHead xss acc
    False -> removeHead xss (acc ++ [tail x])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines like `False -> False` indicate that there is a better way.

```
helper :: Int -> [[Int]] -> Bool
helper v [] = True
helper v xss = let (a, b) = splitAt v xss 
  in verify a && length a `mod` v == 0 -- length a <= v, so why not just length a == v?
  && helper v (removeHead a [] ++ b)

removeHead :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
removeHead [] acc = acc
removeHead (x:xss) acc = removeHead xss
  $ acc ++ [tail x | not $ null $ tail x]
```

Left folds like `removeHead` can often be turned into right folds:

```
removeHead :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
removeHead [] = []
removeHead (x:xss) = [tail x | not $ null $ tail x] ++ removeHead xss
```

`removeHead` needs no explicit recursion. `Data.List.NonEmpty` lets us avoid partial functions (and giving verify a name :) ).

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty

solve :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
solve v = helper v . NE.group . sort

helper :: Int -> [NE.NonEmpty Int] -> Bool
helper v [] = True
helper v xss =
  let (a, b) = splitAt v xss
      (straight, a') = unzip $ map NE.uncons a
  in all (==1) (zipWith subtract straight (tail straight))
  && length a == v
  && helper v (catMaybes a' ++ b)
```

Comment: Thanks Gurkenglas. Can you explain how `[x | _:x@(_:_) <- a]` works

Comment: I guess line 4 should be in it's own function `verify xss = let k = map head xss in
    all (==1) (zipWith subtract k (tail k))`

Comment: `[x | _:x@(_:_) <- a]` is the tail of each element of `a` that has length at least two. That said, pattern matches that logically can't fail but by the types can are smelly. Edited.